# ProductEncoder not working as expected within User Defined Fuction (UDF)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When running the following code in Databricks' notebook:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
  
  case class DataRow(field1: String)
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val udf1 = udf((x: String) => {
    val testData = Seq(DataRow("test1"), DataRow("test2")).toDF("test") // This is failing at runtime
    3
  })
  val df1 = Seq(DataRow("test1"), DataRow("test2")).toDF("test").withColumn("udf", udf1($"test")) // This is working
  display(df1)
```

I get a ScalaReflectionException at runtime:

```
ScalaReflectionException: class $linedb3da7b2933d4b63a62b3d2a21c675f2141.$read in JavaMirror with com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$DriverLocalClassLoader@717115ad of type class com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$DriverLocalClassLoader with classpath [] and parent being com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$ReplWrappingClassLoader@1670897 of type class com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$ReplWrappingClassLoader with classpath [<unknown>] and parent being com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$LibraryClassLoader@1a42da0a of type class com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$LibraryClassLoader with classpath [file:/local_disk0/tmp/repl/spark-4071811259476162981-8e526ae9-25fb-4545-8d3f-963a8661cd2b/] and parent being sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@43ee72e6 of type class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader with classpath [...] not found. 
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:141) 
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:29) 
at $linedb3da7b2933d4b63a62b3d2a21c675f2196.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$$$c35395a9233a7197629c985e87dce75$$$$w$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$typecreator6$1.apply(command-2013905963200886:11) 
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:237) 
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:237) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.encoderFor(ScalaReflection.scala:848) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:55) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:312) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:302) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits.newProductEncoder$(SQLImplicits.scala:302) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:34) 
at $linedb3da7b2933d4b63a62b3d2a21c675f2196.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$$$c35395a9233a7197629c985e87dce75$$$$w$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$udf1$1(command-2013905963200886:11)
```

Declaring the case class within the UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
 
  case class DataRow(field1: String)
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  import sparkSession.implicits._  
  val udf1 = udf((x: String) => {
    case class DataRow(field1: String)
    val testData = Seq(DataRow("test1"), DataRow("test2")).toDF("test") // This is failing at runtime
    3
  })  
  val df1 = Seq(DataRow("test1"), DataRow("test2")).toDF("test").withColumn("udf", udf1($"test")) // This is working
  display(df1)
```

I get a different error

```
error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[DataRow] val testData = Seq(DataRow("test1"), DataRow("test2")).toDF("test")
```

Questions:

- Is this an expected behaviour or a bug?

I also cut [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-44706) as a bug in Apache Spark.

Thanks.

Comment: Using Tuple1 (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/Tuple1.html) instead of DataRow serves as a workaround.

Comment: Where is the case class declaration? I wonder if this could be related to the case class definition being inside another class (as opposed to an `object` typically, or top-level).

Comment: Edit: just saw that you have it in the UDF in 2nd example, that would very likely not work. Move the case class top level outside of any method or class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create datasets within a udf, the SparkContext does not exist on executors.  You can get some behaviour, sometimes, working like that in a notebook or local, but it's not something you should rely on.  Also UDF's, like Expressions cannot return dataset's, only the types supported by Encoders.

The inbuilt implicit product encoder derivations only work with top level classes.  It's not clear from the above code if that is the case or not in the first example, but it's definitely not the case in the second.

Comment: I think you're right about the top level class part of your answer but not about the fact that UDF cannot return Datasets. OP seems to indicate it works fine when using a `Dataset[Tuple1]`.

Comment: Using anything dataset related is not possible if it is run on executors.  The use of Seq toDF uses the LocalRelation plan which does not run on executors so the UDF is run on the driver node.  Change that to range or a file and you'll get npes.